# Scala constructor, logic and inheritance

Tags: scala, constructor

i have a question about scala and logic in constructor. Lets say i have a following code:

```
class A(val x:Int) {...whatever...}

class B(val y:String) extends A(IntValueDerivedFrom_y)
```

Now, how would i derive some value from y and passed it to constructor of class A? I hope it's understandable what i ask about.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I understand. 
You may do

```
class B(val y: String) extends A(f(y))
```

`f(y)` stands for any expression where `y` appears. For instance, `Integer.parseInt(y)`

This is close to java code

```
class B extends A {
   public B(String y) {
       super(Integer.parseInt(y));
   }
}
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah that's it. I tried that approach before but the f in my case was defined inside the class itself which compiler couldnt find (obviously). I moved it to object b and it works properly now. Thanks!